# avoiding cross origin error when running a html and php page locally

Tags: php, html

I have the files test.html and test.php in a directory:

test.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


class NameForm extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)
            }
        }.bind(this)

        xmlHttp.open("GET","test.php",true)
        xmlHttp.send(null)
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        return (<div/>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
</body>
```

test.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST")
echo "this is a test"
?>
```

I can run these on a website however not on my computer, I'd like to be able to run them locally for testing purposes. I have attempted to fix this problem by adding the headers in the php file however this still doesn't work. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: like this:     file:///Users/

Comment: can I do that on my machine without a server?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: ok, I'll look into it, maybe you could give an answer like "this can't be done, do this instead", if you do I'll accept it